# NetSuite workflow "Store Result in" has no fields listed

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript

I am creating a workflow in NetSuite with an action script that returns an integer value. I added the custom workflow field in the same state as the "Workflow action", but for whatever reason the field I added is not coming up in the "Store Result In" dropdown list. It's been a while but I don't remember having a problem with this before. Oddly no fields come up in that list. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Confirm that the custom workflow field is the same data type as the return value of the custom workflow action, integer in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was doing wrong, I had neglected to set the return value I was expecting right on the script record. Thanks for all the help